# Disable locale in datetime display in terminal and logs

Tags: locale

I use Persian loclae. In addition to displaying wrong words for the time, I prefer to display the original English words. Also in system logs. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First edit /etc/locale.gen and make sure that `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` id uncommented.

```
sudo editor /etc/locale.gen
```

Find it and change this:

> #en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8

into this:

> en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8

Next, rebuild locales:

```
sudo locale-gen
```

And then you can set your locale for terminal logins by editing `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile/ and adding:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF8
```

Also if you want to run certain commands with default (English) locales you can put LC_ALL=C in front of them, like so:

```
LC_ALL=C top -d1
```

Comment: In addition to `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` in `~/.bashrc` I would add the line `LANGUAGE=en_US`. Without it, and if the environmental variable `LANGUAGE` is set (which it often is on Ubuntu machines), many entries will be non-English.